# Export form responses to a markdown excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, markdown

I was curious if anyone knows a form app/website that can export the responses to markdown in an excel sheet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are the responses in markdown or you want markdown inside an Excel file?

Comment: There is this online tool that can convert a markdown table into an Excel file, but I doubt this is what you are looking for: https://tableconvert.com/markdown-to-excel